# Python shorthand if or

Tags: python-3.x

Below example prints 5 the first time, and 3 second time. How is that shorthand called? How can I learn more?
I did never see it in any tutorials, just happend to stumble upon it today

```
x = 12
print(x == 12 and 5 or 3) # prints 5
x = 13
print(x == 12 and 5 or 3) # prints 3
```

Comment: That's not a shorthand, these are logical operators. `x == 12 and 5 or 3` is the same as `((13 == 12) and 5) or 3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`and` has a [higher precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) than `or`, so your print statement gets evaluated like `print((x == 12 and 5) or 3)`.

Comment: that doesn't really explain the output. `and` operator returns the last evaluated value. When `x == 13`, it doesn't have to evaluate 5 to know it's false, so it tests `3` which is truthy so you get `3`. Else you get `5` since `or` short-circuits